# syntax of passing arguments to a command

Tags: syntax

From general programming languages, I'm used to calling functions in the following way:

```
myfunction(argument1, argument2, ..., argumentn)
```

It seems like latex requires this syntax

```
\mycommand{argument1}{argument2}...{argumentn}
```

to use commands. Can I call commands using the usual function syntax (instead of writing out braces for every single argument)? I want to be able to do this:

```
\mycommand{argument1, argument2, ..., argumentn}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the command is defined that way, it is possible, but mostly not.

Comment: TeX syntax requires separate arguments, in general, not least because `,` is perfectly valid in general text. We can show you how to define commands that split input at commas, but that won't alter other pre-defined commands. Would that be an answer?

Comment: You're suggesting writing the command so that it splits the argument on commas (as if it were a string)? This is something that has to be programmed into the command and isn't built-in to the language? That's not really what I was looking for.

Comment: it all depends on the command  for example you can do `\usepackage{array,color,longtable,booktabs}`

Comment: @isthisreallife: It always depends on the purpose of the macro whether the comma separated list or the `{}` delimited argument approach is useful. Otherwise you still have to say that the 17th element of the CSV-list should be typeset or processed further within the macro

Comment: I don't think you should do this. If you plan to use TeX a lot, learn to speak it like a native. If you expect to use it rarely, just type the extra braces. The first sentence in @DavidCarlisle 's answer makes sense in many contexts.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have dealt with how one can split at commas, but perhaps some wider explanation is also useful. It's important to start with the fact that whilst LaTeX can be programmed generally, it is a document preparation system for typesetting. The design of the underlying language (TeX) also reflects the same aim, and LaTeX largely uses the same conventions as TeX itself here.

In terms of passing arguments, TeX deals with 'balanced text', which is some arbitrary material (normally) starting with `{` and ending with `}`. The characters used to delimit the 'balanced text' can be altered, but not the fact that we need the two and that they are distinct. That means we have to pass arguments in the form

```
\foo{balanced text 1}{balanced text 2}
```

*etc.* TeX does allow a more complex 'delimited' argument type, so we can set up ([as David as done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364989)) to split material at commas

```
\def\foo(#1,#2){Stuff with #1 and #2}
\foo(abc,def) => #1 = abc, #2 = def
```

but this has to be defined at the programming layer: we can't just 'switch the core syntax'. Moreover, the simple definition I've just used *requires* a comma in the input: if you are modelling on other general languages you are likely expecting the arguments to be optional. One can use more elaborate programming to split at variable numbers of commas, but this will always be a layer *on top* of the core.

One key point to bear in mind is that TeX doesn't have string data or a function/variable split: we have just 'tokens'. Importantly, this means that we might well expect a comma to be used anywhere, and so have to 'protect' commas if we use the \foo(abc,efg) syntax:

```
\foo({abc,def},ghi) => #1 = abc,def; #2 = ghi
```

which (to me) is no clearer than

```
\baz{abc,def}{ghi}
```

Also worth noting here is that using `( ... )` also carries some issues: they can't appear in the arguments without causing issues or without a more complex code set up (see `xparse`).

Answer (score 4):

An `expl3` way (not using `\SplitList` from xparse directly) by defining the command and a processing command that does something with the elements of the argument list, but this processor command does basically do the same operation on the individual elements of the list.

**Note: In case of many arguments that have different meanings, a `key-value` approach is more effective or at least less error prone.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\foocmd}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    \fooprocessorcmd{##1}%
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\fooprocessorcmd}[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}
\foocmd{r,o,f,y,b,i,v}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not always a good idea to force idioms from one language on to another but for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\zz#1{\zzz#1\relax}
\def\zzz#1,#2,#3,#4\relax{\fbox{#1} \fbox{#2} \fbox{#3} \fbox{#4}}
\begin{document}

\zz{a,b,c,d}

\end{document}
```

Note that unlike processing a comma separated list (as for example)

```
 \usepackage{array,color,longtable,booktabs}
```

the `\zz(z)` defined above has a fixed number of arguments, accessed as `#1` to `#4` but using a comma syntax rather than `{}`.

It also assumes the four arguments do not include `,` or `\relax` if they need to they need to be guarded by `{}` so `\zz{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}}`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple `listofitems` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
  \readlist*\myargs{#1}%
  The \myargslen{} arguments are \showitems\myargs.
  The 4th argument is ``\myargs[4].''
}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{this, is, a, big, test}

\mycommand{What, would, you do, for a, Klondike, bar?}
\end{document}
```

[image]